# Magento CMS error : Front controller reached 100 router match iterations

Tags: magento

When I create a page via the CMS (in the admin), everything seems fine but when I try to access the page in the frontend, I get a blank page with an error :

```
Front controller reached 100 router match iterations

#0 ..\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(183): Mage::throwException(’Front controlle...’) 
#1 ..\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(340): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch() 
#2 ..\app\Mage.php(627): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array) 
#3 ..\index.php(80): Mage::run(’’, ‘store’) 
#4 {main}
```

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've had this error in the past. It is caused by Magento not loading the Cms module. No router in the system matches the URL so the default router sets the path as being the 404 page that is set in the admin panel. The default value for this is the Cms index controller, so if the Cms module isn't loaded it ends up in an infinite loop.

The reason is a little harder to guess at. In our case we found that the cache was becoming corrupt when the system was under high load and we cleared the cache directory. It could be fixed by running `rm -rf var/cache/mage--*` until the page successfully loaded. Another cause would be disabling the cms module in `app/etc/modules`.

Comment: I found that I had overriden the Index controller of the csm module (mycompagny/Cms/controllers/IndexController), it worked fine but the PageController was missing , once added, it fixed the infinite loop. Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1):

This is a really good write up of what's going on to create the condition you described.
https://github.com/convenient/magento-ce-ee-config-corruption-bug

The gist is there is a bug which is allowing two processes to invalidate and attempt to rebuild the cache at the same time. This issue was addressed in an official magento patch SUPEE-4755.

There is more on this on the [magento stack site](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/69068/what-is-the-cause-of-front-controller-reached-100-router-match-iterations-erro) too.