# Front controller reached 100 router match iterations, cannot access Magento admin panel

Tags: php, magento

My frontend is working absolutely fine but
I cannot access admin panel.

I am getting following error:

```
Front controller reached 100 router match iterations
Trace:
#0 /hermes/bosnaweb04a/b763/ipg.xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(183): Mage::throwException('Front controlle...')
#1 /hermes/bosnaweb04a/b763/ipg.xxx/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#2 /hermes/bosnaweb04a/b763/ipg.xxx/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#3 /hermes/bosnaweb04a/b763/ipg.xxx/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#4 {main}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Tried flushing caches?

Comment: @DushyantJoshi i cannot access backend, how do i flush cache then?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Magento CMS error : Front controller reached 100 router match iterations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929960/magento-cms-error-front-controller-reached-100-router-match-iterations)

Comment: `rm -r /path/to/magento/var/*cache*`

Comment: your any controller action goes in infinte loop due to this exception occur

Comment: i solved this by using magento-cleanup tool. thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

I follow [this tutorial to fix this issue](http://tutorialmagento.com/fixing-front-controller-reached-100-router-match-iterations). First, as seen from the message, the problem occurs because your routers are making circular references for dispatching requests. One of them matches request, but doesn’t dispatch and pushes it to redispatch again. Or no router matches request at all.
You can get more information by going to Magento Core file **app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php**, find there lines:

```
while (!$request->isDispatched() && $i++<100) {
    foreach ($this->_routers as $router) {
        if ($router->match($this->getRequest())) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

and replace them with

```
Mage::log('----Matching routers------------------------------');
Mage::log('Total ' . count($this->_routers) . ': ' . implode(', ', array_keys($this->_routers)));
while (!$request->isDispatched() && $i++<100) {
    Mage::log('- Iteration ' . $i);
    $requestData = array(
        'path_info' => $request->getPathInfo(),
        'module' => $request->getModuleName(),
        'action' => $request->getActionName(),
        'controller' => $request->getControllerName(),
        'controller_module' => $request->getControllerModule(),
        'route' => $request->getRouteName()
    );

    $st = '';
    foreach ($requestData as $key => $val) {
        $st .= "[{$key}={$val}]";
    }
    Mage::log('Request: ' . $st);
    foreach ($this->_routers as $name => $router) {
        if ($router->match($this->getRequest())) {
            Mage::log('Matched by "' . $name . '" router, class ' . get_class($router));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

After that wait for site to produce the error, open var/log/system.log and see there debugging information about what is going on inside your system. It will help to see much more better, what router breaks the system.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).